# Cannot open shared folder (not enough server storage)

Tags: windows-server-2003

I get an error when trying to access a shared folder on a Windows Server 2003 R2 box. Only happened recently and I am not sure why. I can access a couple of other shares on the server, but not all of them.

> Not enough server storage is available to process this command.

The shares that can be accessed are on a different partition to those that can't. Permissions are set the same on the shared folders (so not a permission error).

Read that there are apparently fixes involving editing the registry, but that is not an 
option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If the symptoms match the common solution, and if you're getting errors in the log that match the description for that common solution...you might have to first try that solution.

Is there a technical reason you can't edit the registry to fix the irp stack size setting?

Comment: Ah, the dreaded IRP Stack Size bug.  I'd also be interested in learning why you can't fix this the correct and documented way.

Comment: Looking at the event log doesn't show any events matching those detailed in the various solutions offered.

Comment: is *anything* in the event logs? It looks like in some cases you won't see anything even if it was irpstacksize.

Comment: Nothing that looks related to the error in question

Comment: Inquiring minds are still curious why you can't edit the registry...IT department policy? Any other pokes and probes could do more damage than good.

Answer (score 0):

Are the partitions/shares full? If so, have you tried deleting some files to free up space?

Comment: Over 2GB free on the partition, so I don't think it is that.